# At what read/write ratio does MyISAM beat InnoDB in performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

I have certain tables that only get written to once every couple of minutes, while being read dozens of times per second. Research has told me that MyISAM is faster when a table has disproportionately more reads than writes, or even read-only.

At what read/write ratio does MyISAM beat InnoDB in performance? Is it worth switching for me in this case, will there be any noticeable difference?

Comment: Test it. Benchmarks that aren't based on your hardware and your software configuration aren't useful, especially when you're looking for a tipping point between two choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yawn.  At those rates, both MyISAM and InnoDB spend most of their time snoozing.  At thousands/sec, things get interesting.

Most of the literature that says "MyISAM is better/faster/whatever then InnoDB" is *old* literature.  InnoDB performance has been improved to the point where it is hard to come up with a benchmark that says MyISAM is faster.  And there are many other reasons for picking InnoDB.

And, of course, the only *useful* benchmark for *you* is to run *your* application both ways.  So, this is a non-answer for your non-question.

Bottom line:  **Use InnoDB.  Period, full stop.**

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/index-on-integer-and-string-fields and my answer there.